owl carousel open image on click in modalview
I created a carousel with owl-carousel. How can i open a image by click in a modal view?
My Html:
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="image/g1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="image/g2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="image/g3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="image/g4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="image/g5.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="image/g6.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="image/g7.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="image/g8.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

My script:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js" integrity="sha512-gY25nC63ddE0LcLPhxUJGFxa2GoIyA5FLym4UJqHDEMHjp8RET6Zn/SHo1sltt3WuVtqfyxECP38/daUc/WVEA==" crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script>
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      loop: true,
      margin: 10,
      nav: true,
      dots: false,
      navText: ["<i class='fas fa-chevron-left'></i>", "<i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 1
        },
        768: {
          items: 2
        },
        1000: {
          items: 4
        }
      }
    })
    $(document).on('click', '.owl-item', function() {
      owlIndex = $(this).index();
      $('.owl-stage-outer').trigger('to.owl.carousel', owlIndex);
    });
  </script>


Can you create a working example for us to check ?
